# Linq left join ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

i have a problem with my request, i search to get equipements with theirs documents

There are tables

EQUIPEMENT:

`+----------+---------+----+
| PMRQTOTM | LIBELLE | TR |
+----------+---------+----+
|     1234 | POMPE 3 |  1 |
|     1245 | POMPE 3 |  2 |
|     1145 | POMPE 4 |  2 |
+----------+---------+----+`

DOCUMENT:

`+----------+------+-------+
| PMRQTOTM | TYPE |  REF  |
+----------+------+-------+
|     1234 | ADR  |  5647 |
|     1234 | DSI  |  5748 |
|     1145 | ADR  |  4758 |
+----------+------+-------+`

the model :

```
public class CapitalisationViewModel
{
    public string PMRQTOTM { get; set; }
    public string LIBELLE { get; set; }
    public int TR { get; set; }
    public List<DOCUMENT> Docs {get; set;}
}
```

And finally ma linq's request :

```
from capi in northwind.CAPITALISATION
from documents in northwind.DOCUMENT.Where(documents => documents.PMRQTOTM == capi.PMRQTOTM).DefaultIfEmpty()
// <== left join
select new
{
  capi.PMRQTOTM,
  capi.LIBELLE,
  capi.TR,
  documents.TYPE,
  documents.REF,
})
```

How can i fill `List<DOCUMENT>` ?

Comment: Could you post the expected end result?

Comment: Currently your code is doing a cross join. Check https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx for left join demo.

Comment: @hbulens i want to return a list of capitalisationViewModel wich contains Equipement data and theirs documents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need left joins when returning master/detail result sets. Just follow the "natural" way:

```
var result = 
    (from capi in northwind.CAPITALISATION
    select new CapitalisationViewModel
    {
        PMRQTOTM = capi.PMRQTOTM,
        LIBELLE = capi.LIBELLE,
        TR = capi.TR,
        Docs = northwind.DOCUMENT.Where(documents => documents.PMRQTOTM == capi.PMRQTOTM).ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```

If you have defined the proper navigation properties in your entity model, you don't even need to think about joins. For instance, normally you would have a navigation property `Documents` in your `CAPITALISATION` entity, so the above would be simple

```
var result = 
    (from capi in northwind.CAPITALISATION
    select new CapitalisationViewModel
    {
        PMRQTOTM = capi.PMRQTOTM,
        LIBELLE = capi.LIBELLE,
        TR = capi.TR,
        Docs = capi.Documents.ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example, it is self-explanatory:

```
            var capLst = new List<CapitalisationViewModel>();

        var cap1 = new CapitalisationViewModel();
        cap1.PMRQTOTM = 1234;
        cap1.LIBELLE = "POMPE 3";
        cap1.TR = 1;

        var cap2 = new CapitalisationViewModel();
        cap2.PMRQTOTM = 1245;
        cap2.LIBELLE = "POMPE 3";
        cap2.TR = 2;

        var cap3 = new CapitalisationViewModel();
        cap3.PMRQTOTM = 1145;
        cap3.LIBELLE = "POMPE 4";
        cap3.TR = 2;

        capLst.Add(cap1);
        capLst.Add(cap2);
        capLst.Add(cap3);


        var docLst = new List<DOCUMENT>();

        var doc1 = new DOCUMENT();
        doc1.PMRQTOTM = 1234;
        doc1.TYPE = "ADR";
        doc1.REF = 5647;

        var doc2 = new DOCUMENT();
        doc2.PMRQTOTM = 1234;
        doc2.TYPE = "DSI ";
        doc2.REF = 5748;

        var doc3 = new DOCUMENT();
        doc3.PMRQTOTM = 1145;
        doc3.TYPE = "ADR";
        doc3.REF = 4758;

        var doc4 = new DOCUMENT();
        doc4.PMRQTOTM = 1145;
        doc4.TYPE = "ADR";
        doc4.REF = 4758;

        docLst.Add(doc1);
        docLst.Add(doc2);
        docLst.Add(doc3);
        docLst.Add(doc4);

        //left join
        var res = (from cap in capLst
                   join
                   doc in docLst
                   on cap.PMRQTOTM equals doc.PMRQTOTM
                   into grouping
                   from doc in grouping.DefaultIfEmpty()
                   select new
                   {
                       cap.PMRQTOTM,
                       doc
                   }).ToList();

        //Capitalisation with Doc List
        var result =
            (from capi in capLst
             select new CapitalisationViewModel
             {
                 PMRQTOTM = capi.PMRQTOTM,
                 LIBELLE = capi.LIBELLE,
                 TR = capi.TR,
                 Docs = docLst.Where(documents => documents.PMRQTOTM == capi.PMRQTOTM).ToList()
             })
            .ToList();
```